# Javascript move the content of textbox to a box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to move the content of a textbox to a Box when the ADD button is pressed as in the picture. Also, this text should be removed with an X button in the above box.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVrne.png)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
// find elements
var box = $("#banner-message")

// handle click and add class
 $('#add').on("click", function(){
   box.append("<p>Some text <button class='text-more'>x</button></p>")
 })
$("body").on('click', '.text-more', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove()
})
```

This is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/v24jh78b/1/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the "click" function:

```
$(".addbutton").on("click", function(){
    var x = $(".textbox").val();
    $(".box").html(x);
})
```

And to remove it with the "x" button:

```
$(".xbutton").on("click", function(){
    $(this).closest("div").find(".box").html("");
})
```

Let me know if it works